# Why does MATCH return integer relevance instead of float

Tags: mysql, match, match-against

I've looked into the boolean full text search documentation of mysql, and there is written, that MATCH will return a float value, together with an example. Everywhere else that I found reference to this states the same, MATCH will return a float point by relevance score.

But when I run this query

```
select 
match(j.name) against('banana* strawberr* coconut*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as score
from juices j
order by score desc
```

I get either a 0 or a 1.

This are some of the lines with a 1 as score:

```
"Banana and strawberry flavor" 
"Apple and banana juice" 
"Coconuts with pickles"
```

In my understanding, the "banana and strawberry" line should get a higher score than the other two, since there are two words matching?

Comment: How the relevance is calculated depends on whether you are doing a BOOLEAN search, and on what table engine is used as well.

Comment: in this case, the table engine is MyISAM. About the boolean search. As far as I know the default operator is OR (edit: The documentation states that when neither + or - is assigned the word is optional)

Comment: Your query does not actually filter any unmatched rows.  `WHERE MATCH(... ) AGAINST (... IN BOOLEAN MODE)` would have excluded the rows where this somewhat magical dual-purpose expression evaluates to 0 (false).  The only other possible boolean result is 1.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot i know, but thats not part of the question. The question is, why is the result of (in my example above) line 1, 2 and 3 always "1". I would expect that that line 2 and 3 would have a lower value than line 1 but a higher value than 0. The boolean mode does not state to return a boolean value. In the documentation the boolean mode enables operators on the against terms like "+ - < > ~" and the match function does actually return the score. the result should be a float nevertheless

Comment: Hmmm... you're right, it is indeed still a float... at least on MySQL 5.6.  Fulltext does not behave all too sanely with small data-sets, however... if those are the only three rows in the table, add more and see if the results become more like you would predict.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot no, this are not the only ones in my tables. As I wrote in the original question: "this are some lines with a 1 score" I have about 1980 lines, i get 1980 lines back (what is correct, since I don't use a where) I get 1970 x the score of "0" (lines that absolutely dont match, what is correct) and 10 x a score of "1" what is almost correct. the lines are really matching some (if not all) words but i was expecting that i would not get 10 x a score of 1 instead i would expect something like 3 x 0.69.. 4 x 0.78... 3 x 0.96....

Comment: What version of MySQL server are you running?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot 5.5.47 . The documentation states that it should work with 5.5. Only the support for InnoDB comes with version 5.6+. I tested it with Percona 5.5, same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just experienced this on one of my tables, where a different table was providing results as expected. Check to verify your table is not set to MyISAM (only returns 1 on match), you'll want InnoDB to get a float value returned on your matches so you can order by matched rank.

Comment: Thank you, this was never statet in the documentation :/

Comment: I know it's rather late, hopefully it'll still be helpful.